# Jquery index removal with var rather than number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove a value of a certain index from a select

This works.....

```
  $(".myselect option:eq(0)").remove();
```

this does not......

```
  var item = 0;
  $(".myselect option:eq(item)").remove();
```

How come?

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
$(".myselect option:eq(" + item + ")").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".myselect option:eq("+item+")").remove();
```